# Need to regularly check windows for changes

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, monitoring

I'm looking for a fast and reliable method to monitor changes in some windows belonging to a application.

After I hit a hotkey I'd like a method to monitor those windows for a change in specific pixels, and if it detect any changes it should trigger an action (more specifically move that window to other coordinates).

I've got a copy of Keyboard Maestro, which could be certainly a help.
Also GrabFS may help.

What's the best way to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PixelPeeper](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) is the only OS X app i've found that comes close to achieving this goal. Unfortunately it only watches a single pixel and has no adjustments for sensitivity.

I too wish to find an app to monitor multiple specific regions of the screen and activate a script when significant changes occur.